# Is there any tool to convert Android xml files to jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to jetpack compose .

Is there any tool to convert Android xml files to jetpack compose

Can we just provide the old xml file and it converts to jetpack compose

also is xml we had the WYSIWYG (drag/drop edit feature) any tool that supports jetpack compose

Comment: https://github.com/pocmo/recompose

Answer (score 14):

Use [recompose](https://github.com/pocmo/recompose) as it helps you to convert you XML code directly into composable kotlin code.

You would need to copy you XML code and just pate the code inside @Composable function it will automatically convert XML cod into composable kotlin code

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: I see that the last commit was on Nov 20, 2020
I wonder if it still working and safe to use now